# Command Prompt Black Screen NVIM

Tags: command-line, ssh, neovim

I'm facing a really annoying issue with CMD these days.
When attempting to launch neovim on Windows, the display is full black and I don't see any output.

Issue is the same when I SSH into a Linux machine and want to do either htop or nano/vim editing.

Tried updating my drivers, updating Windows but nothing seems to fix the issue.

Only way I managed for now to make it kind of work is to enable Legacy Console in the CMD Properties, but even this way there are some strange things happening such as text overlapping and erasing whenever I'm typing.

Console Output Example
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of TERM is to describe which terminal type is connected to the input/output of the current process. The TERM value can help the current process determine what compatibility is needed in order to function correctly.

For executing in Windows Terminal I find I often have to double check the value of TERM environment variable. I find the best performance when it is:
set to the value `xterm-256color`.

You can set the value using the following command:
`export TERM=xterm-256color`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).